# Hitting time for integer random walk

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Suppose there is a random walk on the integer line, where the value cannot go below $0$,
and the process stops when it hits a barrier at value $k$. The goal is to compute the expected number of steps to hit the barrier, starting from $0$.

Up to here, the problem seems to be fairly classic, and known as "monkey at a cliff" or
"gambler's ruin" (with a reflecting barrier), see e.g. [http://www2.math.uu.se/~sea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf).

The difficulty is that in the case I'm considering, the transition probabilities are not
defined to be $p=1/2$ of doing $+1$ and $-1$. Instead, at every time step the adversary is allowed to choose between different transition probabilities, but the expected change must always be at least $0$. For example, the adversary might choose a transition with
probability $p=1/4$ of doing $+3$ and probability $p=3/4$ of doing $-1$. The probability of doing $+0$ is always $0$.

I have tried doing a similar proof as in the case with simple probabilities, but do not know how to account for the varying transition probabilities. I expect the answer should
still be $k^2$ expected steps to hit the barrier, because doing "bigger steps" should only be better on average, but do not know how to show this. Maybe there is some theorem
about random walks that could help ?

Comment: The answer would depend on the transition probabilities...there is not much that can be said only knowing that the expectation is nonnegative.